# Как читать такую формулу?

Tags: математика, ряды

Помогите вспомнить математику 6 класс(
Как читать такую формулу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё что помню - этот знак - это сумма от i до N и от j до M, а вот дальше(

Comment: Эээ, вы не узнали дробную черту?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сумма всех значений `(X+i)/j`, в которых `i` принимает значения от 1 до `N`, а `j` - от 1 до `M`.

```
(x+1)/1 + (x+2)/1 + ... + (x+N)/1 +
(x+1)/2 + (x+2)/2 + ... + (x+N)/2 +
...
(x+1)/M + (x+2)/M + ... + (x+N)/M
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно и мне 5 копеек? :)

Это то же самое, что и

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]